# Google APPS SCRIPT while loop fails if the search value is not found in the first three rows

Tags: google-apps-script

I,m trying to write a script that reads a value from a cell and then searches for the value in a list.
The script works if the search value is found in the first three rows but fails thereafter.

I was expecting to be able to find the value from a long list. My code as follows:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp;
 var mySpreadsheet= ss.getActiveSpreadsheet;



 var mySheet = mySpreadsheet().getActiveSheet;
 //mySheet().getRange("A1").setValue("John");
 var myCell = mySheet().getRange("A1").getValue();
//mySheet().getRange(4,4).setValue(myCell);

var rowNum = 0;
 var myTest = "";


while(myCell != myTest)
{
rowNum = rowNum + 1;
 myTest = mySheet().getRange(rowNum,4).getValue();

}
Logger.log(rowNum)
mySheet().getRange(rowNum,5).setValue(rowNum)

}
```

Comment: Since you are getting data from a single column, then I would use a map to put it into a flattened array, and use the indexOf() or includes() method to find a match

Comment: JavaScript array methods are a value asset in extracting the desired data from spreadsheets using Google apps script. I would suggest that you study all of them carefully.

Comment: Searching one value at a time is a very slow and cumbersome process learn how to use arrays.

Comment: Thanks. I should probably have explained that I,m a complete newbie to APPS SCRIPTS and am more familiar with VBA so it would be useful to understand why the code sometimes works and sometimes fails depending on the location of the search value?

Comment: For debugging questions, please consider posting examples where your code consistently fail, along with error messages, and any other relevant behaviors *in examples*.

Comment: [Edit] to Quote the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Your coding is a bit unorthodox for Google App Script.  Typically, we get an object and then call the methods of that object as I have shown below.

Secondly, it is more efficient to use `getValues()` when you can and loop through the array see [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices).

Here is an example of finding a value in one of the columns.  Remeber javascript arrays start with index 0, not 1, where as `getRange()` using the column number such as 1 for column A.

I typically use `let` to define my variables although others often use `const`.

**Code.gs**

```
function myFunction() {
  let mySpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let mySheet = mySpreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

  let values = mySheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  let myCell = values[0][0];
  console.log(myCell);
  values.shift(); // remove row 1

  let rowNum = values.findIndex( row => row[3] === myCell );
  console.log(rowNum);
  if( rowNum < 0 ) throw "Value: ["+myCell+"] not found!";
  mySheet.getRange(rowNum+2,5).setValue(rowNum+2);  // add 2 because array start from row 2
}
```

**Reference**

- [SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getActiveSpreadsheet())
- [Spreadsheet.getActiveSheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getActiveSheet())
- [Sheet.getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getDataRange())
- [Sheet.getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())
- [Array.shift()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_shift.asp)
- [Array.findIndex()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_findindex.asp)
- [Arrow function =>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)